# Strugging to buid a cython based extensions for pyodide

Tags: pyodide

Strange. I built a wheel with a cython extension using the instructions [here](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide/blob/main/docs/development/new-packages.md). But when I try to load in dist/console.html I get "module not found". It's particularly strange since on my first try I got "no module named numpy" (yes, my module does also depend on numpy). After I built numpy using `python -m pyodide_build buildall --only 'numpy' packages dist` I can now import numpy, but when I try to import my module using console.html in /src/dist I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'newt'`, but I see `newt-1.0-cp310-cp310-emscripten_3_1_14_wasm32.whl` also in the `dist` directory with the newly build numpy wheel. Any suggestions on how one might diagnose this?

Comment: Is your package in `packages.json` (which was recently renamed to `repodata.json`)? If not you should  be able to directly load it by full URL as well.

Comment: It was in repodata.json, but using the URL worked! Thanks.